# Get the $(document).scrollTop() with touchmove in ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, webkit

I want to get the value of `$(document).scrollTop()` on my iOS device using `touchmove`. Strangely, it works on Windows, MacOS, and Android, but it does not work on iOS.

```
 $(document).bind({'touchmove': function(e){
   console.log($(document).scrollTop()); a = true; console.log(a);
 }});
```

[`$(document).scrollTop()` will continue to return the value 0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7I8W.png)

`window.requestAnimationFrame()` also fails.

Anyway, I want to update the `console.log($(document).scrollTop())` value.

Answer (score 0):

.scrollTop would work on $("body") but not $("html, body")

The browser support

IE8, Firefox, Opera: $("html")
Chrome, Safari, Chrome (Mac): $("body")

```
if($.browser.safari)
    scrollElement = $("body")
else
    scrollElement = $("html,body")

scrollElement .animate( {scrollTop: 0}, 100 );
```